# Prove that $\frac{x_1+...+x_n-1 +y}{n}=y$ for $y=\frac{x_1+...+x_n-1}{n-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

I have found this problem as part of a bigger proof concerning inequalities. I thought it was trivial, but after trying several manipulations, I still cannot get it. I am very sure that it is super easy, which is the reason I am getting frustrated.

Prove that $$\frac{x_1+...+x_n-1 +y}{n}=y$$ for $$y=\frac{x_1+...+x_n-1}{n-1}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\frac{x_1+...+x_n-1 +y}{n}=y \Leftrightarrow \\ 
\Leftrightarrow x_1+...+x_n-1=(n-1)y \Leftrightarrow  \\
\Leftrightarrow \frac{x_1+...+x_n-1}{n-1}=y
$$

Answer (score 0):

Just multiply both sides by $(n-1) \not = 0$ and then move the $-y$ on the RHS to the LHS. Eventually divide by $n \not = 0$ to finish the proof.